# How do I approach this combinatorics problem about composition?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions, extremal-combinatorics

The question is from [Bogart's](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~kpbogart/ProjectSummaryRevised1-05.pdf)

> A **composition** of the integer *k* into *n* parts is a list of *n*
>   positive integers that add to *k*. How many compositions are there of
>   an integer  *k* into *n* parts.

To begin, does the integer k itself qualify as a composition? i.e., if we look at 5, then one answer is 5... then 1 & 4, 2 & 3, etc.?

Comment: Well, first we need to assume that $n \leq k$. Now think of $n$ bins among which you want to distribute $k$ objects. Does this ring any bells as to standard theorems/formulas that you probably learned in class/homework/from textbook?

Comment: Hmm OK, so pigeonhole theory? Or, maybe something else.. Let me review some more then. Thank You,

Comment: Yes, the integer $k$ by itself qualifies as a composition.

Comment: Thank You Very Much! Ok I'm getting this better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint to get you started. Write a list of $k$ $1$s with a space between each term. Using only two symbols, a comma and a plus sign, count the number of ways to distribute these two symbols among the $k-1$ spaces.